# Windows Compact Embedded - Include external native files

Tags: windows, file, windows-ce, external, subproject

I have created a Sub project which just prints "Hello World". My goal is to create a C file inside the same subproject but within a folder named "src", also I want to create a H file within a folder named "include".

The H file contains only one function declaration "void printContent();" and the C file contains its definition which prints "Hello Buddy".

I added the C file inside the Source Files section of Sub project and added the H file inside the Header File Section, but when I compile the subproject and try to deploy it on to an emulator, I got an error.

**BUILD: [01:0000000047:ERRORE] NMAKE :  U1073: don't know how to make 'obj\ARMV4I\debug\content.obj'**

I tried to configure the subproject by providing the below lines in the **sources** file of every Sub project.

**INCLUDES= include/**

But nothing changed and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

In wince subproject, sub folders are treated differently in the source file layout.

- Rule No.1 You can't have both *source* and *dirs* files in the same folder.

So you either use one folder, or use several sub folders, then the root folder is clean and have one *dirs* file and several folders, no source file.

- Rule No. 2 Each sub folder should have both *source* and *makefile*

You can copy and then edit the *source* file, the makefile will always be the same.

Ok, if you are going to use subfolder just to make the folder structure cleaner, my suggestion is that you create **2 subprojects**, one is the main subproject; the other includes all your *src* files and its type is set to be **static library**. Then you can link to the static *.lib* file just as you are including them as in a subfolder. Of cource you need to set the additional include folder and input library.